# 'HTML attribute is not serializable' exception (java)

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, document, jtextpane

I have a `Jtable` which uses custom renderer and editor, which use `JTextPane` as editor and renderer, which uses `DefaultStyledDocument` as the text model. The table contains hyperlinks, which are text with `HTML.Attribute.HREF` attribute. In order to save this styled text into database I need to convert the `DefaultStyledDocument` into XML and trying to do that throws this exception:

> `javax.swing.text.html.HTML$Attribute` is not serializable as a key in an `AttributeSet`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTML.Attribute` is not `Serializable`. For some reason Java developers decided not to add serialization support to `HTML.Attribute` as well as `HTML.Tag`. The most probable reason is that `HTMLDocument` which uses them is serialized into HTML text, and thus there's no need to serialize Java objects directly.

It's easy to fix, really. Create your own attribute:

```
public final class LinkAttribute implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -472010305643114209L;

    public static final LinkAttribute HREF = new LinkAttribute("href");

    private final String name;

    private LinkAttribute(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
       return o instanceof LinkAttribute
              ? name.equals(((LinkAttribute) o).name)
              : false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This is roughly the implementation of `HTML.Attribute` class, with `Serializable` interface added.

Use `LinkAttribute.HREF` everywhere you used `HTML.Attribute.HREF`.

Comment: @Igor There's no need to specify `static` in the class declaration. It's supposed to be a top-level class where `static` keyword invalid for class modifier. If you use it as nested class inside another class, then add `static` to your declaration.

Comment: In my code I'm not creating an instance of the class, so I needed to specify it. :) `String href = (String) a.getAttribute(LinkAttribute.HREF);`

Comment: @Igor No, you don't. Keyword `static` is used to make a class member belong to the class as opposed to an object, which is an instance of a class. For a top-level class, i.e. if you create `LinkAttribute.java` and paste the code there, adding `static` to the declaration results in compile-time error: *modifier static not allowed here*.

Comment: @Igor If you use this class a nested class, inside the body of another class, you'll get compile-error at line `HREF = new LinkAttribute("href");`: *non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context*. Eclipse provides a better error message: *No enclosing instance of type Wrapper is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type `TypeOfYourOuterClass`*. This class does not need access to object fields of its outer class, therefore you have to add `static`. But I see no reason why `LinkAttribute` is nested inside another class.

Comment: You're right, I didn't need to, but when I tried creating a separete class file, a bunch of problems came up. I don't know if it's netbeans or just the JDK but with everything I try to do, a problem must come up. Right now I can't add the LinkAttribute.class to the classpath. It's freakin annoying. .NET seems so much easier and staightforward.

Comment: @Igor Just put the source file `LinkAttribute.java` in the same directory where your other .java files are located. That's all: NetBeans would automatically compile it. I can't compare Java to .Net, as I haven't ever worked with .Net. Yet I read a book on C# :).

Comment: @Igor Java and .Net are so different, the approach to programming is common, however they use slightly different programming patterns. Even more, .Net took its inspiration from Java.

Comment: Oh, I see what had been causing this error. I didn't empty out the database, which contained the DefaultStyledDocument which contained the old LinkAttribute class that had been already defined(nested) in the main class.

Comment: Maybe .Net was inspired by Java or Swing, but in my opinion they took it to another level and made it easier to work with. For example, to make the DataGridView, which is the equivalent of JTable in Swing, to have multilined cells, you just need to set that property to true. It also has much more options, which you can set by setting a property.